# specially hard to remove right whitespaces in text with R

Tags: r, regex, rvest

I extracted some text from a web page.

But I have some whitespaces or speciual characters that I can not remove easily.

I tried this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

url <- "http://www.scielo.org.mx/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1607-40412016000100014&lang=es"

page <- read_html(url)
referenes_whitout_end_spaces <- page %>%
  html_elements("p")  %>% 
  .[grepl("(Links)|(doi:)", as.character(.))] %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  gsub("[\n\t\b]", "", .) %>%
  gsub("\\[.*Links.*\\]", "", .) %>%
  gsub("\\s|\\n", " ", .) %>% 
trimws("both", whitespace = "[ \t\r\n\b]")

referenes_whitout_end_spaces
```

but the whitespaces at the end of the references stands.

how I can remove this whitespaces?

Comment: You can slightly modify your call to `trimws` like this: `trimws("both", whitespace = "[ \\h\\v\t\r\n\b]")` It will catch everything you've got. The `h` and `v` are unicode horizontal and vertical whitespace. (RIght now you have `/032`, which is non-printing space.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the HTML page contains a lot of `&nbsp;` HTML entities standing for non-breaking spaces. These entities are converted to literal non-breaking spaces, `\xA0`.

Thus, you can simply add them to the `trimws` function:

```r
trimws("both", whitespace = "[ \xA0\t\r\n\b]")
```

Or, if you want to support all Unicode whitespace:

```r
trimws("both", whitespace = "\\p{Z}+")
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are some funky unicode whitespace characters. To get rid of them, copy them and paste them into the whitespace argument of `trimws`.

```
trimws(referenes_whitout_end_spaces, whitespace="[           ]")
```

The stuff inside the [] is pasted from the bad output.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `str_squish`:

`str_squish` removes whitespace from start and end of string and also reduces repeated whitespace inside a string:

```
library(stringr)

referenes_whitout_end_spaces %>%
  str_squish()
```